# How do I pass a function between view controllers including the variables within the function?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, data-transfer

I'm working on an XCode project in which I have a specific function's variables that I want to be used within all of the view controllers I have. I want to have some data (var oneName = oneNameTextField.text) to be transferred into a different view controller's array (var weapons = ["(oneName),...] ). Is there a way to do this?

I've tried looking into passing by segues, etc, but I only want to store the data within the code of the second view controller, not show the data visually.

In the first controller I have the function's variables that I want to pass to the second view controller.

```
func userEnterData() {
   var oneName = weaponOneNameTextField.text
}
```

In the second view controller, I have the array that I want the stored variables to go into.

```
var weapons = ["\(oneName)",...]
```

The obvious error here is that it doesn't know what oneName is.

Here are some pictures of the actual code:

[first view controller image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOmbA.png)

[second view controller image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvgEq.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to pass the function instead of only the data?

Comment: @PhillipMills i guess i want to pass all of the data inside the function, my bad. :) i edited it.

Comment: Don't store the variables local to a function.  Create a struct or object that has the 6 fields the second controller needs and pass that when preparing for the segue.

Comment: @PhillipMills if I want the variables to be connected to the text fields/buttons etc in my VC, don't I need to have them locally? could you show me an example using code?

Answer (score 0):

you can store the data in a class with static variables:

```
class Data {    
    static let oneName = "someText"
}
```

and then set the oneName in your first view controller:

```
Data.oneName = weaponOneNameTextField.text
```

and in your second view controller:

```
let oneName = Data.oneName
```

or you can use prepare for segue in the first view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? WeaponsPopUpViewController {
        destinationViewController.oneName = weaponOneNameTextField.text 

    }

}
```

and in your second view controller have defined:

```
var oneName = ""
```

Comment: Where would I set the oneName in the first view controller? I get an error when I try to set it, saying that it is supposed to be a function?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add you current code there?